# how to deal with grouped list binding in xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have listview(lvItemSigns) declared in xaml file.

```
VM = new ItemSignsTabViewModel();
lvItemSigns.ItemsSource = VM.ItemSignsListNew;
lvItemSigns.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataCell));
lvItemSigns.GroupHeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(GroupHeaderDataCell));
```

ItemSignsTabViewModel.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, TicketItem>> _itemSignsListNew;

public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, TicketItem>> ItemSignsListNew
    {
        get { return _itemSignsListNew; }
        set { _itemSignsListNew = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

ItemSignsListNew = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, TicketItem>>(sorted);
```

There is an entry field in list item. I need to populate that entry field with a number on a button click.

So, how to get each item from this grouped list and accomplish the task.
I tried to do a foreach loop from the grouped list to get each item and assign a value to that entry. But it wont allow.

How to assign value to that entry in each list item from this grouped list?

Comment: You don't update the entry directly.  You bind the entry to a property on your model, and update your model.

Comment: yes if i update my ItemSignsListNew, then entry gets updated. but the problem is how to update my ItemSignsListNew.

Comment: if it was a list them i can get each item from the list and update the required field and entry would get updated as this is binded.

Comment: both lists should contain the same instances of TicketItem

Comment: Can you show the `ItemTemplate` code? You can achieve this by sending the bound item list as a parameter of the buttons command/handler and change the object value only. I also recommend you to use the `ItemSignsListNew` as a read-only collection (`public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, TicketItem>> ItemSignsListNew { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, TicketItem>>(sorted);`). You don't have to encapsulate it if it would not be changed.